# Just Audio play audio from Cache File using LockCachingAudioSource

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-streaming, just-audio

i streaming music from the web, but to implement a 10second fast forward option i need to read the song from a file or it wouldnt work.

I use LockCachingAudioSource but here is my problem :

The cache files arent being created and i get an error :
Couldnt not open the file (File does not exist)

Here is my code :

```
   getBeat(String type) async {
    print("Entering Get Beat");
    lastBeatType = type;

    AudioManager _audioManager = AudioManager(lastBeatType: type);


    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/beat?type=$type"));

    
  
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final songdata = jsonDecode(response.body);
   
      final audioSource =    LockCachingAudioSource(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/audio?videoId=${songdata["id"]}"));
      
      final cacheFile = await audioSource.cacheFile;
      _audioPlayer.setFilePath(cacheFile.path);


    
    }
  
    return response.bodyBytes;

    
  }
```

Here is the error :

```
TYPE_SOURCE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.melodia/cache/just_audio_cache/remote/2ece43787200df046f1c43c512aead34bdabf2fe7e0b770c9e3bd7e466bc068e: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Any help would be appreciate  !

Comment: did you solve this Hamido

Comment: Unfortunatly no...

Comment: did you tested it ?: 
 audioPlayer?.setAudioSource(LockCachingAudioSource(Uri.parse(url'),)); i mean as a direct run then .play() ,, i think it will run it from file auto if it was available , without to set it manually , also even if it was not availble or if it was first run , still will run it better performance since it mixed  ,, no ?